# Does any one know how to do a weighted average (sumproduct/total) in matrix in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have just started using SSRS 2008 and needs to have a weighted avg for the columns. I know there a recursive sum, but not sure how to use it and achieve it?

If M is month, V is value then I need weighted avg  = M1V1 + M2V2 + M3V3 / V1+V2+V3.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
=Sum(Fields!M.Value*Fields!V.Value)/Sum(Fields!V.Value)
```

should do the trick

Comment: I tried but no success, it says aggregate functions can't be used for the calculated fields :-(

Comment: Are you trying to add a calculated field in the dataset? If so, add a text box/new column to the report, right click on the box and set the expression there.

Comment: I tried both (new column/calculated fields) but still no results.

Comment: I returned a product of the columns in the dataset query and used it to sum in report columns which provided me the weighted avg.